# Request Headers within Python Django

Tags: python, django

What is the best method to extract a HTTP header from the request within my Django view.

The header I need is `X-Auth-Token`.

Would the following be the recommended method ?

```
if request.META['HTTP_XAUTHTOKEN']:
    print "header found"
else:
    print "header not found"
```

Comment: You should use `'HTTP_X_AUTHTOKEN' in request.META` if you don't want an exception if the header is missing, but then, [obviously, yes: Your example is the best method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.META` is a dict, so if that header is not found, your code will fail with a `KeyError`. You can either catch that, or use `request.META.get('HTTP_X_AUTHTOKEN')` instead.